# Convert 2 digit years into 4 digit years and change the format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, format

I have a dataframe with a date column in the following format `"21/03/22 20:00"` which stands for 21 March 2022, 08 PM. I would like to convert that column with the format `"2022-03-21"`. Is there an easy way to do this in R? I've searched in related questions but none of the answers helped me. Thanks

Comment: You can use `as.Date(df1$date, format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")`i.e. `as.Date("21/03/22 20:00", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")#
[1] "2022-03-21"`

Comment: Also, note that 2 digit year is buggy as it may add year in 2000s instead of 1900 for certain cases i.e. `as.Date("21/03/65 20:00", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")#
[1] "2065-03-21"`  So you need some condition to check